# day and night cycle

Tags: magic, astronomy

My fantasy novel takes place on Atho, a planet on the lowest level of the universe. It is sort of like an alternate earth.  Here the nights last three months and the days a little longer...maybe(still not sure about the science).  These inhabitants are similar to humans although I don't want to label the race human.  My question is what do you think these inhabitants sleep cycle would be like?

Comment: Welcome to the site ray.  We have quite a few questions on longer day/night cycles on the site, take a look at these:  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/157/would-a-human-individual-adapt-to-a-change-in-the-day-night-cycle, or http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20107/effect-of-longer-day-night-cycle-on-human-sleeping-patterns

Comment: In addition to the questions mentioned by @James, I'd also suggest [Sleeping on planets with very long days](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/7263/sleeping-on-planets-with-very-long-days), which I think is closer to what you're asking. Really, there are a lot of questions here about sleeping.

Comment: As James and DaaaahWhoosh said, check out some of the other questions and see if they help you. Then you can refine your question a bit to narrow it down some. Your question is a little overbroad, which means that answers will end up being more opinion based and less useful for you. Having multiple narrow questions about different aspects of the world will help us give you quality answers, and will help you better define what you want. It also has the advantage of giving you more opportunities for points, which means more privileges on the site. Unlike other social sites the points do matter.

Comment: thank you all i have to say im happy i stumbled unto this site and are anyu of you writers by chance

Comment: @ray there are certainly some writers around, chat is a good place to find out more about people.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat